# File called 'Flutter' already exists in this location

Tags: java, android, flutter

When i set the Flutter Sdk path i am facing Error Flutter SDK path not given (and one Pop up window open and showing message "File called 'Flutter' already exists in this location") on Android Studio using mac book pro can you handle this solution Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

The trick is not to click on `Install Sdk` while creating new flutter project but instead give path in the respective text box. 
When you click on `Install Sdk` and take it to your flutter folder, android studio creates a new folder flutter inside your flutter folder and copies all the files.

Comment: You're right. By clicking on Install SDK, Android Studio is trying to install the Flutter SDK into your specified path while generally that path already contain your SDK downloaded separatelly and installed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the fact that you have a file somewhere called `flutter`. Note that when you download the Flutter SDK using Android Studio will download the SDK into a folder, not a file. For example I downloaded my Flutter SDK in my user folder:

```
$ ls /Users/gi097/flutter
AUTHORS             README.md               examples
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  analysis_options.yaml   flutter_console.bat
CONTRIBUTING.md     bin                     packages
LICENSE             dartdoc_options.yaml    version
PATENTS             dev
```

So, first of all make sure that the folder you choose does not contain a file called `flutter` before downloading the SDK.

If that does not work, you can also download the SDK manually like the following:

```
$ cd /Users/yourusername
$ git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter
$ ./flutter/bin/flutter doctor
```

Now you can just set the `/Users/yourusername/flutter` as the SDK location when opening Android Studio or Visual Studio Code. You can also run direct commands with only Flutter itself e.g.:

```
$ ./flutter/bin/flutter run
```

It's also worth nothing to read the following manual: https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install

Answer (score 0):

When you set the Flutter Sdk path you are facing Error Flutter SDK path not given (and one Pop up window open and showing message "File called 'Flutter' already exists in this location") on Android Studio using mac book pro can you handle this solution

Please change your project name and it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the file that has the same name on the location.
It worked for me.